# Getting error while creating CustomerProfileId in Authorize.net

Tags: drupal-7

Hello I'm trying to use the CIM API, but when calling its `createCustomerProfile()` method, I get to the error code "E00003" with text *"Name cannot begin with the '0' character, hexadecimal value 0x30. Line 2, position 344."*
I am using Authnet Module provided for Drupal 7.

I am using array of `$values`;

```
$cust_profile = authnet_customer_profile_new($values);

$customer_profile = authnet_cim_profile_save($cust_profile);
```

Again, I'm not generating this XML - it's automatically done by the PHP SDK.
Any ideas for how to solve this issue? It's been messing with my head all day...